# Installing mongodb driver for PHP on MacOS

Tags: php, mongodb

I am having some issues installing mongodb driver for PHP on MacOS.  The PHP I have on my laptop came with MacOS and the version is:

> PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 20:10:18) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018
>   Zend Technologies

I have followed instructions on disabling csrutil and installed pear with the following command:

```
curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar 
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

And then I am trying to install mongodb with the following command:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

The problem now is that the compilation fails with "include file not found" error.  I have Xcode development and command line tools installed and have looked all over for answers but I can't seem to crack this error.

While installing the include paths are found by pecl (as shown below) but when it comes to compiling it is erroring out as below:

> /usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file
>   not found
>
> ## include "pcre.h"
>
> ```
>      ^~~~~~~~
> ```

Following a suggestion on the web I even included the path to header files with C_INCLUDE_PATH but doesn't work.

> checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php
>   -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
>   checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php

Can someone please throw some light on this?  I am at my wit's end on this :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue.  Although php_pcre.h file was located in the include path, pcre.h wasn't.

I ran the install with the following command (setting the path for pcre header files) and that did the trick:

```
sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/pcre pecl install mongodb
```

Phew!